# Find basis for exact matrix form of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

$A:\cal{P}_1 \to \cal{P}_1$ is a linear operator defined with
$$
A(p)(t):=(3t+1)p'(t)+2p(t).
$$
I'm trying to find a basis $e$ of $\cal{P}_1$ in which the operator $A$ has the matrix form
$$
A= \begin{bmatrix} 4 &2 \\ 1 &3  \end{bmatrix},
$$
and determine if there exists a basis $f$ in which the matrix of this operator is diagonal.

I've tried this:

Let $e=\{e_1, e_2\}$ be the basis of $\cal{P}_1$ which we need to find. I have
$$
A(e_1)(t)=(3t+1)e_1'(t) + 2e_1(t) = 4e_1(t)+e_2(t),
$$
$$
A(e_2)(t)=(3t+1)e_2'(t)+2e_2(t)=2e_1(t)+3e_2(t).
$$
From these two equations it follows that
$$
2e_1(t)+e_2(t)=(3t+1)e_1'(t) = (3t+1)e_2'(t),
$$
which means that $e_1$ and $e_2$ are of the forms
$$
e_1(t)=at+c_1, \ e_2(t) = at+c_2.
$$
When I put this back into the initial equations for $A(e_1)$ and $A(e_2)$ I get $a=2c_1+c_2$, $\textit{and after some manipulation I get $c_1=c_2$}$. But if this holds, then $e_1$ and $e_2$ are equal, and thus do not form a basis. Where did I go wrong and how do I make it better?

EDIT: Okay, now I've tried without manipulating the part I put in $\textit{italics}$ (maybe I had an error there) and put $c_1=0, \ c_2=1$. Now I have that the basis is
$$
e_1(t) = t, \ e_2(t) = t+1,
$$
which $\textit{is}$ a basis in which the operator has that matrix. However, now I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Let me write $at+b$ as $\begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\end{bmatrix}$. Then, in the canonical basis, 
$$\tag{1}
A=\begin{bmatrix}5&0\\1&2\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
We get this by noticing that the differentiation operator is $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and then $(3t+1)p'$ is given by $\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

From $(1)$ we immediately see that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $5$ and $2$. A basis of eigenvectors is easily seen to be 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\end{bmatrix},\ \ \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
That is, $3t+1$ and $1$. So $A$ is diagonalizable; in particular
$$\tag{2}
\begin{bmatrix}1/3&0\\-1/3&1\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}5&0\\1&2\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}5&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
As for the basis so that the matrix is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 4 &2 \\ 1 &3  \end{bmatrix},
$$
I don't know if you find the following "elegant". The eigenvectors of this matrix satisfy
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 4-5 &2 \\ 1 &3 -5 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2y-x\\x-2y\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So $\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector for $5$; for $2$,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 4-2 &2 \\ 1 &3 -2 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2(x+y)\\x+y\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This gives us an eigenvectors $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$. 
Then
$$\tag{3}
\begin{bmatrix} 1/3 &1/3 \\ 1/3 &-2/3  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 4 &2 \\ 1 &3  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 &1 \\ 1 &-1  \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} 5 &0 \\ 0 &2  \end{bmatrix}
$$
Comparing $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get 
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} 4 &2 \\ 1 &3  \end{bmatrix}
&=\begin{bmatrix} 2 &1 \\ 1 &-1  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 5 &0 \\ 0 &2  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1/3 &1/3 \\ 1/3 &-2/3  \end{bmatrix}\\ \ \\
&=\left(\begin{bmatrix} 2 &1 \\ 1 &-1  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1/3&0\\-1/3&1\end{bmatrix}\right)\begin{bmatrix}5&0\\1&2\end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1/3 &1/3 \\ 1/3 &-2/3  \end{bmatrix}\right).
\end{align}
So
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 3 &0 \\ 1 &1  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1/3&1/3\\1/3&-2/3\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\2/3&-1/3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is a change of basis between the canonical basis and one where 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}4&2\\1&3\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then the first element is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\2/3&-1/3
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2/3\end{bmatrix},
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\2/3&-1/3
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1/3\end{bmatrix}.
$$
That is, $t-2/3$ and $t+1/3$ make up another basis where  $A$ has the form $\begin{bmatrix}4&2\\1&3\end{bmatrix}$.

*Note:* any invertible matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&c\\ b&d\end{bmatrix}$ such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}5&0\\ 1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&c\\ b&d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a&c\\ b&d\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}4&2\\ 1&3\end{bmatrix}
$$
will yield a basis $at+b$, $ct+d$ in which $A$ has the form $\begin{bmatrix}4&2\\ 1&3\end{bmatrix}$